# list-style-type: lower-alpha without "k", "w" and "y"

Tags: css

I'm transforming portuguese plain text to structured text (html), to present it in a website, and I found a peculiar problem.

At some point the text has a list of bullets of the form:

```
<p>a) (.*)</p>
<p>b) (.*)</p>
...
<p>j) (.*)</p>
<p>l) (.*)</p>
```

which I'm structuring as

```
<ul>
    <li>\1<\li>
    <li>\1</li>
    ...
    <li>\1</li>
</ul>
```

It is important that they are rendered as in the original text, which I'm doing using `list-style-type: lower-alpha` on the list.

However, when I do this, the items become `a.`, ..., `j.`, **`k.`** (and not **`l.`**). I.e. they are in the english alphabet, which has the letter k.

I searched for it in the [W3C specs on lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/PR-CSS2-19980324/lists.html#list-props), but it seems it leaves this in ambiguity:

> **lower-latin** or **lower-alpha**:
>        Lower case ascii letters (a, b, c, ... z).

My question is: is there any way to solve this? The way I'm doing it now is to use

```
<li>a) \1<\li>
```

with `list-style-type: none`, but other solution would be very helpful.

Comment: So portuguese does not use the letter K? That is very surprising is that letter missing on your keyboards?

Comment: That is a good point that led me to find that "k" was indeed introduced in 1990. The issue is that I have documents from as old as 1910.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you have two options use a definition list where you can define your own prefix or like I would recommend add an empty `<li />` tag which has the style `display:none`.

Here is a example for the definition list:

```
<dl>
  <dt>a)</dt>
  <dd>some text</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: I didn't knew definition list <dl>. Very nice. Thanks!